# Как получить все ключи url из объектов, которые находятся в массиве, который находиться в объекте?

Tags: javascript

Подскажите пожалуйста как получить все ключи url из объектов, которые находятся в массиве, который находиться в объекте? Прикрепляю скрины пути у url в console и в файле.То что в кнсоле плучил с помощью JSON.parse().Теперь нужно получил все url для вывода на страниу.  [image: введите сюда описание изображения][image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
let imageUrls = galleryImages.map(image => image.url);
```

`imageUrls` - массив со всеми значениями из всех `url`